# React Native Hook Proceed after Dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, dispatch

I am trying to run method after dispatch but when i am dispatching redux state, it runs code after dispatch before its completely dispatched.

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            dispatch(
              addData({
                name: "Test Name",
                phone: "0000",
              })
            );
            // dataReducer is the variable which returns state of reducer using selector
            console.log("Added Data: " + JSON.stringify(dataReducer)); //returns []
          }}
        >
          <Text>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

And if i press again it returns updated array. It means state is update after onpress is completely rendered. I want onPress not to complete until data is completely dispatched and then move on to next row. I checked there is no callback method attached with useDispatch(). Kindly guided what is the better way.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet i just posted the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const setReducerState = () => {
dispatch(
     addData({
     name: "Test Name",
     phone: "0000",
   })
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setReducerState()}>
          <Text>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You won't be able to log state immediately due to async nature.

**EDIT**

Yes you can pass callbacks after dispatch.

```
dispatch({
<your action>,
callback: () => {
 //what you want to do here
}
})
```

Now where you are getting your action in reducer

```
case action.yourActionType:
     action.callback(); // this callback you wanted
```

Comment: Basically this TouchableOpacity  is over Flatlist renderItem. Each item of Flatlist have onPress method. I want to update each item name onPress via Reducer

Comment: Did you give it a try, are you able to get name "Test Name"?

`setReducerState()` , you can pass name to this function whatever you want.

Comment: Is there a way we can add callback after dispatch?

Comment: @DIGITALJEDI refer to answer EDIT for your answer.

Comment: its giving me syntax error. I tried adding callback as you mention in my add action.

Comment: What's the error? and update question with how you doing that?

Comment: Update your question with the progress and the error? Thanks